# Gmock: save a pointer of a passed argument or compare by address in expected call

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Suppose I have a method

```
void Mock::foo(const A& obj);
```

and I want to check that it was called exactly with the object `obj` rather than its copy:

```
A obj;

EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(obj));

mock->foo(obj);
```

How can I check this? I found `Address(m)` matcher [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/heads/77A9B20B4C1E02FAC90D1D942E1D4C18/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md). But I cannot find it in `::testing`, i.e. it does not compile.

Comment: You are using to old version of gtest: https://godbolt.org/z/MzjvnGP99

Comment: Here is [implementation of that matcher](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/100f6fbf5f81a82d163c1e29735e8a2936eacd4f/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h#L4992-L4996) and [detail](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/100f6fbf5f81a82d163c1e29735e8a2936eacd4f/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h#L2978-L3018). This [feature](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/e5644f5f12ff3d5b2232dabc1c5ea272a52e8155) was released with 1.11.0.

Comment: OMG, I did not know that godbolt allows using 3rdparty libraries and even to choose versions. Thank you. However, the 11th version is quite "fresh" and not everybody has access to it. So I hoped for an older option to solve the problem.

Comment: @MarekR Could you, please, tell what 'd' is at the end of -lgtest_maind in the linkage? On Linux I have libgtest_main.so and so compile -lgtest_main. Where can I learn about how I can link on godbolt?

Comment: this provides standard `main` function and apparently on godbolt it is build in debug version and this fact is marked with `d` suffix. I do not have source for that.

Comment: But  how did you learn that you need 'd'? Just curious. @MarekR

Comment: I do not remember. I've wrote "I do not have source for that". It is possible I just found this by trials and errors (suffix `d` is quite often used).

Comment: Long time ago I've created couple bookmarks to gobolt I'm finding useful. For example [catch2](https://godbolt.org/z/PWrccT), or [confrmance](https://godbolt.org/z/oYh5TMnT1). Those are starting points for most things I do on that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, [`::testing::Address()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.11.0/docs/reference/matchers.md#pointer-matchers) matcher was introduced in GoogleTest 1.11.

You can use instead [`::testing::Ref()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#generic-comparison) matcher, which does the same thing underneath (comparing addresses) and is available since at least GoogleTest 1.8 ([see it online](https://godbolt.org/z/YMdhM6cb1)):

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

struct Data
{};

struct Mock
{
    MOCK_METHOD(void, foo, (const Data& d), ());
};

struct ClassUnderTest
{
    Mock* dependency;
    void methodUnderTest(const Data& d)
    {
        dependency->foo(d);
    }
    void methodThatCopies(const Data& d)
    {
        Data copy = d;
        dependency->foo(copy);
    }
};

TEST(X, Correct)
{
    Mock m;
    Data d;
    ClassUnderTest uut {&m};

    EXPECT_CALL(m, foo(::testing::Ref(d)));
    uut.methodUnderTest(d);
}

TEST(X, Fail)
{
    Mock m;
    Data d;
    ClassUnderTest uut {&m};

    EXPECT_CALL(m, foo(::testing::Ref(d)));
    uut.methodThatCopies(d);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```